# Remove non-text chars (like emoticons) from string

Tags: php, regex, unicode, preg-replace, str-replace

How can I replace chars like  from a string? Sometime the YouTube video title contains characters like this. I don't want to replace characters like !@#$%^&*().

I am currently using `preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $VideoTitle);`

Samples Array:

```
$VideoTitles[]='Sia 2017 Cheap Thrills 2017 live '; 

$VideoTitles[]='TAYLOR SWIFT - SHAKE IT OFF  #1989';
```

Expected Output:

```
Sia 2017 Cheap Thrills 2017 live 
TAYLOR SWIFT - SHAKE IT OFF #1989
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code with sample input: [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8c35069f0e0ee559eec5ce4d0398a5fa153c922e)

```
$VideoTitles=[
    'Kilian à Dijon #4 • Vlog #2 • Primark again !?  - YouTube',
    'Funfesty   on Twitter: "Je commence à avoir mal à la tête à force',
    'Sia 2017 Cheap Thrills 2017 live '
];

$VideoTitles=preg_replace('/[^ -\x{2122}]\s+|\s*[^ -\x{2122}]/u','',$VideoTitles);  // remove out of range characters and whitespace character on one side only

var_export($VideoTitles);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Kilian à Dijon #4 • Vlog #2 • Primark again !? - YouTube',
  1 => 'Funfesty on Twitter: "Je commence à avoir mal à la tête à force',
  2 => 'Sia 2017 Cheap Thrills 2017 live',
)
```

The above regex pattern uses a character range from `\x20-\x2122` (*space* to *trade-mark-sign*).  I have selected this range because it should cover the vast majority of word-related characters including letters with accents and non-English characters.  (Admittedly, it also includes many non-word-related characters.  You may like to use two separate ranges for greater specificity like: `/[^\x{20}-\x{60}\x{7B}-\x{FF}]/ui` -- this case-insensitively searches two ranges: *space* to *grave accent* and *left curly bracket* to *latin small letter y with diaeresis*)

If you find that this range is unnecessarily generous or takes too long to process, you can make your own decision about the appropriate character range.

For instance, you might like the much lighter but less generous `/[^\x20-\x7E]/u` (from *space* to *tilde*).  However, if you apply it to either of my above French `$VideoTitles` then you will mangle the text by removing legitimate letters.

Here is a [menu of characters and their unicode numbers](https://unicode-table.com/en/#2122) to help you understand what is inside the aforementioned ranges and beyond.

*And remember to include a unicode flag `u` after your closing delimiter.

---

For completeness, I should say the literal/narrow solution for removing the two emojis would be:

```
$VideoTitle=preg_replace('/[\x{1F3A7}\x{1F3AC}]/u','',$VideoTitle);  // omit 2 emojis
```

These emojis are called "clapper board (U+1F3AC)" and "headphone (U+1F3A7)".

Comment: The OP's data didn't contain linebreaks. If you need to protect linebreaks add them to the negated character class.  Do you have a new issue for me to look at?

Comment: Thank you, very comprehensive answer. I've ended up using from `0020` to `00F0` (Basic Latin & Latin-1 Supplement) for my case scenario (mostly italian, plain text).

Answer (score 1):

```
function removeEmoticon($text) {

    $cleanText = "";

    // Match Emoticons
    $regexEmoticons = '/[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}]/u';
    $cleanText     = preg_replace($regexEmoticons, '', $text);

    // Match Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs
    $regexSymbols = '/[\x{1F300}-\x{1F5FF}]/u';
    $cleanText   = preg_replace($regexSymbols, '', $cleanText);

    // Match Transport And Map Symbols
    $regexTransport = '/[\x{1F680}-\x{1F6FF}]/u';
    $cleanText     = preg_replace($regexTransport, '', $cleanText);

    // Match Miscellaneous Symbols
    $regexMisc  = '/[\x{2600}-\x{26FF}]/u';
    $cleanText = preg_replace($regexMisc, '', $cleanText);

    // Match Dingbats
    $regexDingbats = '/[\x{2700}-\x{27BF}]/u';
    $cleanText    = preg_replace($regexDingbats, '', $cleanText);

    return $cleanText;
}
```