# Remove emoji but not non english chars

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to remove all emoji chars from string and below code works fine except it remove non English characters too, How can I avoid this?

```js
var ranges = [
  '[\u00A0-\u269f]',
  '[\u26A0-\u329f]',
  '[-]'
];


$('#submit').on('click', function() {
  var str = $('#text').val();
  str = str.replace(new RegExp(ranges.join('|'), 'ug'), '');
  $("#text").val(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text"/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="clear"/>
```

Sample emoji for test: ⛔️
Sample non english: آ

Comment: You are matching three ranges, one of which starts at U+00A0: ie. where the code points for accented characters (and combining accents) are encoded. Try reducing to just the emoji range.

Comment: Wikipedia has an [**entry**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticons_(Unicode_block))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a single pattern with a broad character range:

```
/[^ -\u2122]+ +| *[^ -\u2122]+/ug
```

My method is essentially ported from this php answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43106144/2943403

It will remove one or more emojis at a time and space characters on one side (but not both).

```js
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
  $("#after").html($('#before').val().replace(/[^ -\u2122]+ +| *[^ -\u2122]+/ug,''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="before" cols="75" rows="5">Sample emoji for test: ⛔️ Sample non english: آ Kilian à Dijon #4 • Vlog #2 • Primark again !?  - YouTube Funfesty   on Twitter: "Je commence à avoir mal à la tête à force Sia 2017 Cheap Thrills 2017 live </textarea><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Remove Emojis"/><br>
<textarea id="after" cols="75" rows="5"></textarea>
```

---

I'll add an update for those that have issues / concerns about my answer:

Here is an alternative regex pattern declaration and the pattern itself can be extended to include characters lower on the ascii table (including newline characters):

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
  var r = new RegExp(/[^\u0000-\u2122]+ +| *[^\u0000-\u2122]+/, "ug");
  $("#after").html($('#before').val().replace(r,''));
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6ha01nsb/11/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I copy your code in my workspace (visual studio) it return an error, also on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7u9a02t7/) but not in browser console log.`Expected ')' and instead saw 'ug'.`

Comment: where is the rest of the fiddle?

Comment: here is a blind guess: try adding an extra ` \ ` before each ` \ ` .

Comment: Look like `u` is useless here, remove it, fix it. But another problem with this answer, it also remove *new line*, but replacing `''` with `'\n'` maybe help you but not a clean.

Comment: Alternative syntax for regexp declaration: https://jsfiddle.net/6ha01nsb/5/  I'll paste the two lines for easier reading: `var r = new RegExp(/[^ -\u2122]+ +| *[^ -\u2122]+/, "g");
  $("#after").html($('#before').val().replace(r,''));`